# Having problems understanding how to use DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to convert a html page to a dom object in order to grab information from the page

the following code gives me nothing but errors, so whatever I am doing is wrong

**php code**

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://google.com');
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
echo $dom->saveHTML(); 
return;
```

error example

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 34 in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php on line 32
```

can anyone tell me what I should be doing?

Comment: PHP's dom is **VERY** picky about malformed HTML. This is one place where supressing the errors with `@` is somewhat permissible, because dom will complain about trivial things that aren't really errors.

Comment: You can put `libxml_use_internal_errors( true);` before the `$dom->loadHTML();` call. This will suppress those errors, as they're complaining about Google's malformed HTML.

Comment: is it normal to suppress php dom errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know if this is going to fix your problem but try the following. Using [tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) to clean up html.

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://google.com');

// Specify configuration
$config = array(
           'indent'         => true,
           'output-xhtml'   => true,
           'wrap'           => 200);

// Tidy
$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($page, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();


$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($tidy);
echo $dom->saveHTML(); 
return;
```

Comment: I have no idea what tidy is and im getting a `Fatal error: Class 'tidy' not found ` error